# Unable to hide inner element with height or width 0px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to toggle a div using it's width or height. But when i am setting it's width to 0 it's inner element is visible. So, how to achieve this toggle width functionality?

[js fiddle](https:///jsfiddle.net/fq9wzrnx/15/)

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: orange;
}

div {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is a para</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working. and think sometimes padding affect on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` do the `div` in css.

Comment: I think, it's not hide after hight:0 because of overflow of an element is visible by default. What do you say?

Comment: Yes, overflow is visible by default, that's why you need to add `overflow: hidden;` to it.